# How do I line up an html document for print so the pages are not cut off?

Tags: html, css, iframe, layout, printing

I've got a HTML document within an iframe that people will be printing off, I've coded it to look good when it prints. There's a footer and a header, the header changes for each page and each page is within it's own div tag. I want people to be able to hit the print button for the document and the pages each print on their own page without getting cut off and making sure the footer stays at the bottom of each page. Is there a way to do this? I'd love some help with this as it's driving me crazy! It looks like crap when like a page is too short so the next page will print on the same page and then get cut off halfway through.

This is where I have it set up..
http://morecleanenergy.com/graphics/testproposal/index.html

Here is one of the pages..

```
<div style="size:210mm 297mm;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="Proposalheader">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="169"><img src="faq.png" height="57px"></td>
            <td width="732"></td>
        </tr></table>
    <div class="pageBody">
        <span class="generalText"><p><strong>Who is Clean Energy Collective?</strong></p>
            <p>Clean Energy Collective (CEC) is a Colorado-based company that develops, operates and maintains community-owned solar arrays, also referred to as solar gardens or community solar farms. CEC's innovative model makes local renew- able energy easy, accessible and a financially smart decision for electricity consumers in the United States.</p>
            <p><strong>What is CEC Community Solar?</strong></p>
            <p>Clean Energy Collective community solar enables you to own solar panels in a centralized, community-based array. As your panels produce clean electricity, you receive credits directly on your monthly electric bills for the power produced. By owning a solar power system in a community array, you can reduce or eliminate your electric bills, protect against rising prices, and experience monthly savings in place of a monthly expense.</p>
            <p><strong>What happens to the electricity produced by the panels?</strong></p>
            <p>The clean solar power is automatically delivered to the Xcel Energy's grid, increasing the utility's incorporation of renewable energy and decreasing its reliance on fossil fuels. The power is not delivered directly to your meter and no equipment is required to be installed on your property.</p>
            <p><strong>Do I need to own a home or building to participate?</strong></p>
            <p>No. If you have an electric bill, you can receive credits for the power produced by solar panels in a CEC communi- ty-owned solar array.</p>
            <p><strong>How can I monitor my panels' performance?</strong></p>
            <p>As a CEC customer, you can log on to your My Own Clean Energy account via the CEC website and smartphone app. There you can see your system's information, review your customer documents, and access real-time information about your portion of the array's production, bill credits, and positive environmental impact.</p>
            <p><strong>What happens if I move?</strong></p>
            <p>If you move within your county, simply have your panels' bill credits applied to your new location's meter and account with the utility. If you leave the county or the Xcel Energy territory, you may sell the panels to another Xcel Energy customer in your county or give a tax-deductible gift of clean energy by donating the system to a charity in your county.</p>
            <p><strong>How much solar can I buy?</strong></p>
            <p>Systems are available from a minimum of 1 kilowatt (kW) up to 120% of your average annual usage.</p>
            <p><strong>How are my monthly electric bill credits calculated?</strong></p>
            <p>Each month, your Xcel Energy electric bill will be credited for your panels' production. The power produced is credited at the specific rate for your customer class as determined under Xcel Energy's Solar*Rewards Community Program. These initial credit rates will increase as Xcel Energy's electricity rates increase, protecting you against the national trend of rising electricity costs.</p>
            <p><strong>How are my monthly electric bill credits calculated?</strong></p>
            <p>As Xcel Energy's electricity prices rise, the bill credit rate you receive for the panels' output will increase as well. As your monthly bill credits increase, your system's savings increase.</p></span>
    </div>
    <div><img src="footer.png" style="width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying the page-break-after css property to your footer. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Comment: How do I implement this then? Would I add a <div class="footer"> to like the end of each page?

Comment: It looks like you already have a div at the end of each page to display a footer image. Adding a class to it, like you mention, and setting that class as "page-break-after: always" should give you the effect you want.